# Query to bring top 3 users from top 3 cities in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I have a location (city) table and a user table. I need to retrieve the 3 top users from 3 top cities (where a city is considered as a top 3 depending on how many users there are in it), with the city information. Example:

**Miami (q = 95000)**

1. Andrea
2. Debra Morgan
3. Gabriela

**New York (q = 74000)**

1. Sandy
2. Carsie
3. Megan

**San Diego (q = 26500)**

1. Ursula
2. Ramona
3. Romina

This is my current query:

```
SELECT l.city, l.q, u.name 
FROM location AS l JOIN user AS u 
ON l.id_location = u.id_location 
ORDER BY q DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

The obvious problem is that it is only bringing me the top 3 users from the top 1 city. Any ideas?

These are the tables:

**location**

- id_location
- name
- q (amount of users)

**user**

- id_user
- name
- picture

Comment: how do you know which are the top 3 users of a city? is there a field that you can use to order users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GROUP_CONCAT function to concatenate all users, and SUBSTRING_INDEX to return only the first three users:

```
SELECT
  l.city, l.q
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.name ORDER BY field_to_order DESC), ',', 3
  ) AS top_3_users
FROM
  location AS l JOIN user AS u 
  ON l.id_location = u.id_location
GROUP BY
  l.city, l.q
ORDER BY
  l.q DESC
LIMIT 3
```

result will be something like this:

```
Miami     95000    Andrea, Debra Morgan, Gabriela
New York  74000    Sandy, Carsie, Megan
San Diego 26500    Ursula, Ramona, Romina
```

**Edit** if you also need the picture of the user, and the picture is a VARCHAR, then you can use GROUP_CONCAT also on that field:

```
SELECT
  l.city, l.q
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.name ORDER BY field_to_order DESC), ',', 3
  ) AS top_3_users,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.picture ORDER BY field_to_order DESC), ',', 3
  ) AS top_3_pictures
FROM
  location AS l JOIN user AS u 
  ON l.id_location = u.id_location
GROUP BY
  l.city, l.q
ORDER BY
  l.q DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Forgot to tell you, I still need the user's picture field as well :s

Comment: @andufo is the picture a varchar field? or is it binary?

Comment: it is a varchar (255)